# Wordpress - Custom template within plugin using template_include

Tags: wordpress, templates, plugins, themes, overriding

### The case

I'm creating a WordPress plugin with some predefined *.php pages, located inside the template folder of the plugin. So this folder contains files like "login.php", "register.php" & "activate.php".
These template-pages could be overwritten by a theme. So my plugin should hook the `template_include` WordPress filter in order to check if the used theme make use of template-overriding. If so, WordPress should load the `theme template`, otherwise the predefined `plugin template` should be loaded.

To determine which template should be used for a page, you could select a page inside the Admin area of WordPress by using my plugin (See picture below)

### The problem

I don't know how to get the path of the choosen template for a page. [This](http://jeroensormani.com/how-to-add-template-files-in-your-plugin/) tutorial is helpfull but doesn't 100% match my needs. So I came up with the following code to retrieve the page ID of the template to be retrieved. But since the ID of the template could change, I don't want to hardcode anything. As a result of that I don't know how to continue. Maybe someone could point me into the right direction?

```
add_filter('template_include', 'getTemplate');
function getTemplate($template)
{
    global $post;

    /*
    $pages = array (
       'Register' => 2,
       'Login' => 3,
       'Logout' => 5,
       'Activate' => 7,
       'Password reset' => 9,
      )
    */

    $pages = get_option('myPlugin-pages');
    $page_id = $pages[$post->post_title];

    // Whats next?

    return $template;
}
```

#### Picture explanation

According to the following picture, the left & bold positioned text is the hardcoded name of the plugin pages. So my plugin requires 5 pages. At the right there is a dropdown with a list of all the pages registered by WordPress. When you save these settings, a record is added/updated to the `wp_options` database table, with a option name like `myPlugin-pages`.

[image]